# How to correctly close a Windows.Forms dialog and return something different than "Cancel"?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I defined a form which I show as a dialog as per `myForm.ShowDialog`. The form sets the `AcceptButton` property correctly to my button. When I call the `Close()` method, the dialog result is always `Cancel`.

I searched about this issue and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163753/winforms-close-sets-dialogresult-to-cancel) where they suggest to manually set `DialogResult` when it should be different to `Cancel`.

Since VB.net offers me to set an "Accept" button I find this "solution" quite hackish though. The documentation for the `AcceptButton` property says that it determines which button is "clicked" when the user presses the Enter key. I also expected that would automatically set the DialogResult to "OK" but it does not seem to do so.

So, is manually figuring out which button was clicked and updating the `DialogResult`, which looks like cleaning up after the Microsoft guys who designed Windows Forms, the way to go or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AcceptButton does not close the form automatically. This is because it is just the default button which gets "clicked" if you press Return. If you set the DialogResult in the buttons click event handler, the form gets closed directly so you don't need to call `.Close()` anymore, so this seems not to be a bug to me.

Comment: OK. I did not think it was a bug either, it was just a misunderstanding. I did not expect the AcceptButton to automatically close the form, but as I wrote, I expected it to at least update the DialogResult, or at least a second Close method to be offered by Windows Forms that takes a DialogResult as a parameter.