# I'm trying to start a form with ShowDialog and it returns DialogResult.Cancel. Why is this?

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog, dialogresult

```
Progress progress = new Progress();//progress.DialogResult is OK.
if (progress.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
{//progress.DialogResult is cancel.
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

In the debugger it says that the result is DialogResult.Cancel.
Why is this?
I have a form with just a progress bar and a label. Nothing more.
I have opened and closed some other forms as well if this matters.
The form doesn't open.

Progress class:

```
public partial class Progress : Form
{
    public Progress()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool filesLength = false;

    public void OnWordsChanged()
    {
        if (!filesLength)
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = Program.numberOfFiles;
            filesLength = true;
        }
        progressBar1.Value = Program.wordsDone;
    }
}
```

and designer:

```
 partial class Progress
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "label1";
        // 
        // progressBar1
        // 
        this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 30);
        this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
        this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(259, 23);
        this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // Progress
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        this.Controls.Add(this.progressBar1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "Progress";
        this.Text = "Progess";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar1;
}
```

Comment: sounds weird, can you include your Progress class?

Comment: OK, I'll do that thought I just clicked new form and dragged a progress bar and a label in.

Comment: a quick and simple test... rip some stuff out and try again.  If you can identify the item that needs to be removed you'll be 99% to a solution!

Comment: Or, put a breakpoint on new Progress() line, then F11 for step by step debugging afterwards

Comment: I've just tried:
deleting form and trying again
removing both elements
.
It still gives cancel

Comment: "The dialog box can be assigned one of the values of the DialogResult enumeration by assigning it to the DialogResult property of a Button on the form or by setting the DialogResult property of the form in code." from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx says that you can set a DialogResult property on the form itself... check the property inspector to see if that's set to Cancel.

Comment: I've already tried setting form.DialogResult to OK.
The result of creating the initial form is OK.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx also try using a different class name than Progress which seems to be taken...

Comment: OK, I've just tried renaming to ProgressForm, no change.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7163805/6138713) and from [Form.DialogResult Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx).

> When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close
>   button (the button with an X in the top-right corner of the form)
>   causes the form to be hidden and the DialogResult property to be set
>   to DialogResult.Cancel. The Close method is not automatically called
>   when the user clicks the Close button of a dialog box or sets the
>   value of the DialogResult property. Instead, the form is hidden and
>   can be shown again without creating a new instance of the dialog box.
>   Because of this behavior, you must call the Dispose method of the form
>   when the form is no longer needed by your application.

Meaning by default, when you close a form it will have DialogResult.Cancel unless it is overridden.

Comment: @Ephriam, I haven't closed, it closed on its own with DialogResult.Cancel.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 have you tried assigning it first to a DialogResult variable and compare it from there?

Comment: @Ephriam yes, I also tried assigning it to DialogResult.OK afterwards.